# individual tri-state output IC with SPI / I2C / shift register input

Tags: shift-register, expander

Is there any simple non-MCU IC that allows switching several outputs (8 or more) tri-stated, eg. set any output to either high (~2V), low or open individually ?

Input may be shift-register, SPI or I2C.

Comment: When it came out, all of us started using the [74**595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf?ts=1643495492323) for this kind of thing. It was a god send, so to speak. Octal, serial in, separately latched, and tri-state. What's not to like? I bought buckets of them.

Comment: Comes in at least these: [LS595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls595.pdf), [HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf), [AHC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc595.pdf), and [AHCT595](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74AHCT595.pdf). So plenty to work with. If you need independent control of the tri-state mode on the outputs, then use two of them (one for the data and one for the tri-state controls) to drive a tri-stating octal buffer. If you tell me this works, I'll write up an answer that lays out the details. If there's a problem, I'll await why.

Comment: Better, of course, would be a cheap MCU. But you specifically want to avoid that obvious, cheaper, and smaller (if slower) solution.

Comment: @jonk, the 595 doesn't meet the question as asked, which clearly says an IC with I/O/hiZ per pin. That's not multiple ICs.

Comment: @TonyM Yes, I know. Notice that I didn't answer? Which is why I also asked for reasoning from the OP. I don't know if the OP specifically requires ***separate*** tri-stating control for the outputs, or not. It's not clear from the writing. And also, although a single IC is desired, the OP didn't specifically exclude more if separate control is required. I am looking for clarification of the question for obvious reasons.

Comment: @jonk, And an MCU is much worse as it's nowhere near cheaper with the software development, qualification testing, support and programming costs. That has to be factored into the total cost and has to be paid out of this year's budget, so considering it spread over the product lifetime don't help today's costs. What one can knock off alone has nothing to do with actual costs. Having two lines of application code in an MCU incurs a big overhead, far higher in some firms than others. This gets ignored by some so so often on this site and so so never in professional engineering and manufacturing.

Comment: @TonyM Most of us have toolsets and experience using MCUs. If you are an engineer today and lack these tools and skills you are seriously hobbled. It's an essential set of skills and tools for the modern engineer. Besides, MCUs are quite cheap. About 4-5 cents per pin in 1's. Of course, dronus has every right to suggest otherwise for a specific application. That's their absolute right.

Comment: @jonk, I'm afraid you've completely missed the point by so far...it's nothing to do with capabilities.

Comment: @TonyM I guess I'm not able to be so confident and strident from so few words from the OP. I'll leave things for the OP who needs to write.

Comment: @jonk, I'm lost. I'm not responding to OP but to you on your point, where an MCU solution was described as 'cheaper' and 'obvious' ("*Better, of course, would be a cheap MCU. But you specifically want to avoid that obvious, cheaper, and smaller (if slower) solution.*") Business costs aren't a sign of confidence or stridency, nor are they an opinion of mine. I just don't understand why why you'd only considered parts costs, not this big unavoidable expense. Have invited you to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133667/discussion-between-tonym-and-jonk) on this, too much here.

Comment: @jonk yes, I ask for individual / seperate tri-state action, eg. have some pins drive low while some other pins are high Z.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Many of them. They are called GPIO expanders. They are made by many manufacturers, and have either I2C or SPI interface.

Some of them, from some manufacturers that make MCUs, might be pre-programmed MCUs, but I don't see why it would make a difference if it is actually an MCU or not.